# Commands description syntax

Tags: linux, syntax

What is the name of syntax that usually is used while defining Linux commands like below:

```
apt [-h] [-o=config_string] [-c=config_file] [-t=target_release]
    [-a=architecture] {list | search | show | update |
    install pkg [{=pkg_version_number | /target_release}]... |
    remove pkg... | upgrade | full-upgrade | edit-sources | 
    {-v | --version} | {-h | --help}}
```

I understand that `|` means or.
I suppose `[]` means optional
Have no idea about `{}`

Comment: That way since original UNIX manuals in 1971. http://man.cat-v.org/unix-1st/1/ls Note owner (author) of page dmr (Dennis Ritchie) and ken (Thompson).

Answer (score 0):

> What is the name of syntax

There is no such syntax and it has no name (well, unless you make up some). It is that developer personal convention how to write usage. It's not governed by any "standard", it's just text written by that particular programmer. I see that [usage message](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_message) is even on wikipedia.

The `{}` seems to represent some groups here, like `{-v | --version}` mean the same and are to get versions. Ask the developer.

The most standardized argument synopsis would be [posix utility conventions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/basedefs/xbd_chap12.html). There are "coding standards" and "good patterns" to use etc., there are libraries like [GNU argp](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argp.html) or python argparse - but these all are "conventions", not requirements. On the end, it's developers choice what text he wants to print when developing his tool and he can print anything.